# Clip-path is shown destorted

Tags: html, css, svg

i am recomposing this question and i apologize for the messy first try. i made a clean html and css example to show the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div id="test">test</div>

<svg width="1" height="0.67" viewBox="0 0 1 0.67" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <clipPath id="mypath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <path d="M0.765561 0.669377C0.759194 0.669006 0.752816 0.66799 0.746517 0.666302L0 0.466273V0.0948509C0 0.0424662 0.0424659 0 0.094851 0H0.905149C0.957534 0 1 0.0424662 1 0.0948509V0.479892L0.838139 0.641753C0.821451 0.658442 0.799442 0.668047 0.77656 0.669377H0.765561Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
    



</html>

<style>

#test{
    display: block;
    background-color:rgb(0, 167, 50);
    width:369px;
    height:247px;
    clip-path: url("#mypath");
}

</style>
```

this is the div without the clip-path:
https://ibb.co/zRW7KTd

this is the div with the clip-path:
https://ibb.co/ZYvt6Lt

but the svg with the clippath is made to the exact size of the div and the result is that the clipping path has the right width, but the height is compressed, distorted.

this is what the svg looks like in the first place, having the same size and aspect ratio as the div:
https://ibb.co/Jqy76gp

so why the distortion? its driving me a little crazy..

Comment: Can you please show us a working example? You have provided an SVG some CSS, nothing to check out.

Comment: sadly, im quite sure im not allowed to do that :( maybe just a screenshot

Comment: i redid the whole post, hopefully you guys can help me, thanx in advance!

Comment: trying to bump this post, hope thats allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I have remade the SVG with the same size as the div:

```css
#test{
    display: block;
    background-color:rgb(0, 167, 50);
    width:369px;
    height:247px;
    clip-path: url("#mypath");
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 369 246" style="enable-background:new 0 0 369 246;" xml:space="preserve">

    <clipPath id="mypath">
<path d="M184.5,0c49.5,0,99,0,148.4,0C353.8,0,369,15.3,369,36.2c0,45,0,89.9,0.1,134.9c0,3.8-1.1,6.5-3.8,9.2
    c-18,17.8-36.2,35.4-53.7,53.8c-12,12.6-25.4,15-41.7,10.4c-31.4-8.9-63-17.1-94.5-25.5c-39.2-10.5-78.4-21.1-117.6-31.6
    C41,182.8,24,178.2,7,174c-4.8-1.2-7-2.9-7-8.6c0.3-43.1,0.2-86.3,0.2-129.4C0.2,15.4,15.6,0,36,0C85.5,0,135,0,184.5,0z"/>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I got it from watching a clipPath tutorial on YouTube: the problem was that the units of the path inside the svg were absolute and not relative. I had to use https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/ to convert the path units from `userSpaceOnUse` to `objectBoundingBox` (as seen on the mentioned website) - in other words, from absolute to relative. I replaced the whole `d` attribute of the path with what I got from yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/ and now it works just fine.